# How to set a maximum amount of features to be drawn in every zoom level

Tags: openlayers-2, features, generalization

I want to apply a form of generalization/specialization to my OpenLayers map. Is there a way to set the amount of WFS features to be rendered based on the zoom level?

In GeoServer you can set the maximum amount of features but not based on a zoom level. Would something like this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good way to minimize unneccessary traffic is to use a BBOX-Strategy:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    url:  "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
                    featureType: "tasmania_roads",
                    featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
                })
            });
```

Otherwise you can use "maxFeatures=xxxx" to limit the number of features delivered but with this solution you can't decide with features will be sent back.

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=1.1.0&
  request=GetFeature&
  typeName=namespace:featuretype&
  maxFeatures=N
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using alread a BBOX strategy. Setting the maxFeatures to be returned can not be per zoom level Only in total. Correct?

Comment: you can just watch the zoomend-event,change the maxCount according to the zoomlevel and reload the layer

Comment: I think this is what I want. I already check the zoomend event: (map.events.register("zoomend", map, function(){... Can you please provide an example of to set the maxCount?

Comment: layer.protocol.options.maxFeatures = 20 and refresh.refresh(); ( see http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/Le5wfgdy/ ) but as the maxCount gives you a random limitation still not very satisfying...

Comment: Yes that's true. The randomness factor doesn't give optimized result. I thought to make a simplification of my shape file. The number of linestrings won't change (around 4k) but the complexity of each one will (instead of 20 coords each will be 3 or 4). You think that would actually improve speed? Or the number of features to be rendered is still high and the render process doesn't depend on the complexity of the feature? (in terms of coordinates).

Comment: yes this should increase the speed a bit but it will still be a lot to render ;)